# android : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-async-http

Getting the following error while running the project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Before it was running well.

I am trying to integrate the [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

The page says to integrate the following line:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

So, my resultant build.gradle is:

```
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-bosh:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.3'
    compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:0.5.0-alpha6'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/volley-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile project(':emoji')
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0"
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
...
```

Please help me out.

**PS:** I am working on ubuntu 15.0.4 with Android Studio 1.4 beta 4. Java version is Oracle java 8 update 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0"
```

with

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
```

Comment: Dont use play-service library direct because its contain too many library within it.Please check out this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Upvoted. Worked.. But didn't get the "-gcm:" part.. Why this needs to be added?

Comment: Because only play-services:7.8.0 have so many option included in it that why multiple dex problem occour. if you need to ignore that you have to use only the part which u need. e.g. play-services-gcm:7.8.0

Comment: http://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup Go through this official Document by android developers.